# '-999' used for all condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample of a stored procedure like this (from my previous working experience):

```
Select * from table where (id=@id or id='-999')
```

Based on my understanding on this query, the '-999' is used to avoid exception when no value is transferred from users. So far in my research, I have not found its usage on the internet and other company implementations.

@id is transferred from user.

Any help will be appreciated in providing some links related to it.

Comment: `-999` is just a `constant` they have used as default to _avoid exception_. it can be anything `apple`, `mango` , but should be `unique` at the same time.  In this case `-999` might be unique as `id will never be -999 if the user is inputting the values`. They could have used `-888` or `-1000` also

Comment: can you provide me some links on it, I just want to confirm this. thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't see how is this going to help avoid any exception.

Comment: yes, but I want to know that is there any logic behind using '-999' as data don't have id '-999'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add my two guesses on this, although please note that to my disadvantage, I'm one of the very youngest in the field, so this is not coming from that much of history or experience.

Also, please note that for any reason anybody provides you, you might not be able to confirm it 100%. [Your oven might just not have any leftover evidence in and of itself](https://kryogenix.org/writings/stories.html).

Now, per another **[question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225175/why-do-some-people-use-999-or-9999-to-replace-missing-values/)** I read before, extreme integers were used in some systems to denote missing values, since text and `NULL` weren't options at those systems. Say I'm looking for ID#84, and I cannot find it in the table:

---

1. **Not Found Is Unlikely:**

Perhaps in some systems it's far more likely that a record exists with a missing/incorrect ID, than to not be existing at all? Hence, when no match is found, designers preferred all records without valid IDs to be returned?

This however has a few problems. First, depending on the design, user might not recognize the results are a set of records with missing IDs, especially if only one was returned. Second, current query poses a problem as it will always return the missing ID records in addition to the normal matches. Perhaps they relied on `ORDER`ing to ease readability?

---

2. **Exception Above SQL:**

AFAIK, SQL is fine with a zero-row result, but maybe whatever thing that calls/used to call it wasn't as robust, and something goes wrong (*hard exception, soft UI bug, etc.*) when zero rows are returned? Perhaps then, this ID represented a dummy row (*e.g. blanks and zeroes*) to keep things running.

Then again, this also suffers from the same arguments above regarding "*record is always outputted*" and `ORDER`, with the added possibility that the SQL-caller might have dedicated logic to when the -999 record is the only record returned, which I doubt was the most practical approach even in whatever era this was done at.

---

... the more I type, the more I think this **is** the oven, and only the great grandmother can explain this to us.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid exception when no value transferred from user, in your stored procedure declare parameter as null. Like `@id int = null`

for instance :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TableCheck]
    @id int = null
AS
BEGIN

    Select * from table where (id=@id)
END
```

Now you can execute it in either ways :

`exec [dbo].[TableCheck] 2` or `exec [dbo].[TableCheck]`

Remember, it's a separate thing if you want to return whole table when your input parameter is null.

**To answer your `id = -999` condition, I tried it your way. It doesn't prevent any exception**

Comment: I want to know why it is being used over here, I searched it on internet and many people who used it doesn't know that the reason.

Comment: @J.Doe : Please post your whole stored procedure to analyze it better.